# Linux system files moved, how to return by booting from an installer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, mv

So I accidentally 'sudo mv' my files from /* (root directory) to some directory inside my home directory. My OS stopped working and I rebooted. Then I encountered the

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
```

I can't boot to my linux OS anymore. So I boot from my flash drive with a linux installer. I can still find my linux installation from one of the devices, and the system files that I moved. The problem is that I can't move them back.

The directories left in the device with corrupted linux installation are: dev, home, proc, run, sys

I'm running Linux Mint 17

Comment: *"The problem is that I can't move them back."* -> Why? How did you try?

Comment: can't paste into the filesystem? don't know how to cd to it too

Answer (score 2):

LiveCDs usually have something like a "Root terminal" you can open to do things as the superuser.  From there, you should be able to `cd` to where the filesystem is mounted and simply `mv` the relevant directories.  For example, if the mount point is `/mnt/fs`, and you want to move the `/mnt/fs/home/me/whatever/etc` directory back:

```
> cd /mnt/fs
> mv home/me/whatever/etc /mnt/fs
```

If this was all within one partition (i.e., your home directory is not separate), the original move didn't really do much, but it still might have created a problem in process. So before you do anything, check the drive for corruption.  First find out what the device node is:

```
 > mount | grep "/mnt/fs"
 /dev/sda2 on /mnt/fs type ext4
 ^^^^^^^^^
```

The reply above is just an example to show what the device node is, in this case, `/dev/sda2`.  Now:

```
> cd /
> umount /dev/sda2
> e2fsck /dev/sda2
[ may take 10-20 seconds, showing progress ]
> mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/fs
```

Now you are sure everything is okay, you can do the `mv` stuff.